# Can I put 16GB of RAM and 4GB GTX 1050 Ti in a H81 Motherboard?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard

I am going to buy a H81 Motherboard. But it says maximum memory supported is 16GB in their specs. I want to know if i put 16GB of RAM, is it possible to put a GTX 1050 Ti of 4GB VRAM. Does VRAM account for maximum memory budget? I googled few different time and i could not find a correct answer.

Comment: *Does VRAM account for maximum memory budget?* - VRAM is isolated to the GPU and has nothing to do with the amount of memory that can be installed in a motherboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of GPUs: Integrated and dedicated.

An integrated GPU is the one that comes with your motherboard.
The usual case is that both the CPU and the GPU are included on the
same chip and both share the computer memory (RAM).

A dedicated GPU comes completely separate from your CPU and
with its own memory in the form of VRAM (video RAM, or video
random access memory), which gives the dedicated GPU quick access
to image data and better performance.

Whatever dedicated GPU you install in the computer, it will not
use the RAM for display. The GTX 1050 Ti is a dedicated GPU.